# How can I get value from a select field?

Tags: laravel, dropdown, html-select, crud

I have a livewire CRUD component to make posts. It worked perfectly before I tried to add a choice of categories. This is a piece of code, where I try to choose a category:

```
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
      <option wire:model="category_id" selected>Выберите категорию</option>
          @foreach($categories as $category)
          <option value="{{ $category->id }}">
             {{ $category->name }}
          </option>
     @endforeach
     @error('category_id') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
</select>
```

I can display all the categories and choose one, but I can't get it in the component. I have tried to use a checkbox element. I was even validated, whenever I chose a category or not. The select field isn't validated at all. I can just output all the categories from the db.

Here is my CRUD component.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Category;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Post;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class Posts extends Component
{
    public $title, $categories, $category_id, $body, $post_id, $search, $img;
    public $isOpen = 0;

    use WithFileUploads;
    use WithPagination;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->categories = Category::all();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $search = '%' . $this->search . '%';
        $posts = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', $search)
            ->orWhere('body', 'LIKE', $search)
            ->latest()
            ->paginate(5);

        return view('livewire.posts.posts', ['posts' => $posts])->layout('layouts.app');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $this->resetInputFields();
        $this->openModal();
    }

    public function openModal()
    {
        $this->isOpen = true;
    }

    public function closeModal()
    {
        $this->isOpen = false;
    }

    private function resetInputFields()
    {
        $this->category_id      =      '';
        $this->title            =      '';
        $this->body             =      '';
        $this->post_id          =      '';
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'category_id'    =>    'required',
            'title'          =>    'required',
            'body'           =>    'required',
            'img'            =>    'image|max:1024'
        ]);

        Post::updateOrCreate(
           ['id'             =>    $this->post_id],
           ['category_id'    =>    $this->category_id,
            'title'          =>    $this->title,
            'body'           =>    $this->body,
            'img'            =>    $this->img->hashName(),
        ]);

        if(!empty($this->img)) {
            $this->img->store('public/docs');
        }

        session()->flash('message',
            $this->post_id ? 'Пост успешно обновлен.' : 'Пост успешно создан.');

        $this->closeModal();
        $this->resetInputFields();
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $post                   =     Post::findOrFail($id);
        $this->category_id      =     $post->category_id;
        $this->post_id          =     $id;
        $this->title            =     $post->title;
        $this->body             =     $post->body;
        $this->img              =     $post->img;
        $this->openModal();
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        Post::find($id)->delete();
        session()->flash('message', 'Пост успешно удален.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will setting a `name` for select solve the problem?

```
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="category_id">
      <option wire:model="category_id" selected>Выберите категорию</option>
      @foreach($categories as $category)
      <option value="{{ $category->id }}">
         {{ $category->name }}
      </option>
     @endforeach
     @error('category_id') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
</select>
```

Currently it doesn't seems like framework can identify the name for this input